# Enviar Array em um input como string para php do javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Olá!

Gostaria de colocar um array de objetos dentro de um input e enviar para o php usando o form montado no JQuery

No momento estou testando assim:

**Meu objeto**

```
const myObject = [
   { id: 1, nome: 'Stackoverflow' },
   { id: 2, nome: 'Linux' },
   { id: 3, nome: 'Broffice' },
   { id: 4, nome: 'MS Office' },
  ]
```

O que eu gostaria de colocar esse `myObject` em um input:

Eu tentei assim:

```
  let myStrObj = JSON.stringify( myObject )
  let form =  $('<form action="backend.php" method="post">'+
                 '<input type="hidden" name="objecto" value="'+myStrObj+'">'+
                '</form>'
               )
  $('body').append( form )
  form.submit()
```

Só que desse jeito, no php chega dessa maneira com o `json_decode( $_POST['objecto'] )`:

```
[{
```

Só isso

Por que que eu quero assim?

Porque é um processamento que eu quero o que backend faça e não precise me retornar, senão eu usaria assim:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'backend.php',
   type: 'post',
   ...
})
```

Como não consegui fazer da maneira acima, eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
   let inputDados = ''
    $.each( myObject , ( i, j )=> {
        inputDados += `<input type="hidden" name="dados[${i}][id]" value="${j.id}">
        <input type="hidden" name="dados[${i}][nome]" value="${j.nome}">`
    })
```

E monto meu formulário assim:

```
      var form =  $('<form action="backend.php" method="post">'+
                       inputDados +
                    '</form>'
                   )
      $('body').append( form )
      form.submit()
```

E no php chega assim:

```
array(
  0 => array(
       id => 1,
       nome => stackverflow
   ),
  1 => array(
       id => 2,
       nome => Linux
   ),
   2 => array(
       id => 3,
       nome => Broffice
   ),
   3 => array(
       id => 4,
       nome => MS Office
   )
)
```

Tem outro jeito melhor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) para serializar o JSON:

```js
function generateInputHTMLWithJSON(inputName, data) {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'hidden';
  input.name = inputName;

  // Serializa o JSON e o coloca na propriedade `value` do input:
  input.value = JSON.stringify(data);
  
  // Evita erros na serialização:
  return input.outerHTML;
}

console.log(
  generateInputHTMLWithJSON('data', [
    { username: 'Foo', age: 10 },
    { username: 'Bar', age: 20 },
    { username: 'Baz', age: 30 }
  ])
);
```

No exemplo acima, a propriedade [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) foi utilizada para *gerar* um HTML *válido* sem risco de dar conflitos com as aspas do JSON, que serão propriamente escapadas para `&quot;`.

E no PHP:

```php
json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: Então praticamente tem que ter um elemento input criado na página propriamente e não no javascript?

Comment: Nesse caso o input foi criado via JavaScript.

Comment: Porque você o comando `document.createElement` que cria o elemento na página, correto?

Comment: O `document.createElement` não insere o elemento no DOM a não ser que você utilize algo como o `appendChild`. Nesse caso, é como se o "input" ficasse na memória. Só usei o `createElement` para ter acesso à propriedade `outerHTML`. :)

Comment: Muito bom! Muito obrigado!